# Pointer Not Pointing Correctly?

Tags: c++, windows

I am running this code in a thread, assuming receivedPosts and td->window are valid:

```
std::vector<Post> *receivedPosts_n = new std::vector<Post>;
*receivedPosts_n = receivedPosts;

SendMessage(td->window, WM_TIMER, IDT_TIMER_FIND_NEW_POSTS_CALLBACK, 
    (LPARAM) receivedPosts_n);
```

I'm running this code at IDT_TIMER_FIND_NEW_POSTS_CALLBACK (hwnd is td->window):

```
case IDT_TIMER_FIND_NEW_POSTS_CALLBACK:
    {
        std::vector<Post> *currentPosts_ptr = (std::vector<Post> *)lParam;

        //This vector turns up as undefined
        std::vector<Post> currentPosts = *currentPosts_ptr;
    }
    break;
```

But the problem is that *currentPosts_ptr turns up as an invalid pointer, i.e. it points to random memory.

What is wrong with the pointer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that for WM_TIMER message value of lParam is

> A pointer to an application-defined callback function that was passed to the SetTimer function when the timer was installed.

If you need to send custom messages it is much better idea just to use [WM_USER through 0x7FFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that were specially designed for this scenario.